# Reproducir video con VLC wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy trabajando con VLC para reproducir videos en WPF me da el siguiente error

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo
>   'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' en Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll
>   pero no se controló en el código del usuario Información adicional: %1
>   no es una aplicación Win32 válida

La implementación es la siguiente

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Name="usrComunicacion" x:Class="GestosCorporales.WpfApplication.View.ComunicacionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GestosCorporales.WpfApplication.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="314.662" Background="White" d:DesignWidth="623.684" Loaded="usrComunicacion_Loaded">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Comunicación" FontSize="13" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="20">
        <Grid Margin="15">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="600"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Grid base partido Dos columnas y una fila-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <GroupBox Name="gbInteraccion" Header="Interacción" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label Name="lblStatus"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="vlcPlayer" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="280" Height="240" />
                    <Canvas Name="skeletonCanvas" Background="Black" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="280" Height="240" />
                    <!--Resultados Videos y Movimientos-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="Traducción" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Name="lblTraducion" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Botones-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
                        <Button Name="btnEscuchar" Content="Escuchar" Width="200" Margin="3" Click="btnEscuchar_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="btnCargarMov" Content="Cargar Movimiento" Width="200" Margin="3"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>


            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Segunda columna/Dos row-->
                <GroupBox Name="gbVideo" Header="Video" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Image Name="imgVideo" Margin="5" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </GroupBox>

                <GroupBox Name="gb3D"  Header="Profundidad" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Image Name="imgVideo3D" Margin="5" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

codigo C#

```
public ComunicacionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory =
            //replace this path with an appropriate one
            new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();//En esta línea me da el error que muestro líneas arriba.
    }
```

Lo raro es que esta implementación ya lo había hecho y no había problemas, la implementación lo hice siguiendo esta referencia.

[Integrate VLC player in C# (WPF) project using Vlc.DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723674/integrate-vlc-player-in-c-sharp-wpf-project-using-vlc-dotnet)

Y pasando al proyecto real me sale el error que menciono, estoy siguiendo todas las recomendaciones.

El código del proyecto de prueba es el siguiente

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ReproducirVideoVLC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReproducirVideoVLC"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="vlcPlayer"/>

</Grid>
```

Código C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory =
        //replace this path with an appropriate one
        new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri(@"D:\PruebasCSharp\ReconocimientoVoz\Video\WPF Media Element.wmv"));
    }
}
```

> La única diferencia es que en el proyecto real uso un UserControl y en
>   el proyecto de prueba uso Windows(ventana).

Acabo de hacer mas pruebas en el proyecto real he colocado la misma implementación en un Windows(ventana) y da el mimo error.

En el proyecto de prueba he agregado un usercontrol hice la implementación y no da error.

Mi equipo es una pc con SO Windows 10 64 bits, lo raro es que en la implementación de prueba que realice no me salió ningún error.

Comment: podes probar sacar el control ese del inicialize del control, y hacerlo disparar con un boton? tengo miedo que como es un user control, y no se termino de inicializar el padre, el problema venga por ahi

Comment: Intenta eliminando esa línea y prueba nuevamente. Si no funciona, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la documentación oficial: https://zahidakbar.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/using-the-vlc-activex-control-in-wpf/

Comment: @Richard a que línea te refieres?

Comment: vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();

Comment: Supongo que no tenga nada que ver, pero fijate tambien si el proyecto es de 32 o 64 bits.

Comment: @Pikoh Es de 64 bits

Comment: @Richard Siguiendo el ejemplo no me sale la versión del vlc plugin1 inprovise con el único que había en COM y me quede varado en System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            if(ofd.FileName != string.Empty)
            {
                vlc
            }

Comment: @Richard vlc no tiene la propiedad addTarget estoy usando using AxAXVLC; si haces el ejemplo te darás cuenta de lo que te digo.

Comment: @Pikoh el instalador será creado para 64 bits

Comment: @Richard encontré la propiedad adecuada pero los parámetros que le paso parece no ser el que el esperaba recibir.vlc.playlist.add(ofd.FileName, null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo);

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de solucionar el problema, tenía desmarcado en el Buil la casilla de Preferentemente 32 bits.

[image: Preferentemente 32 bits]